# ASP.NET "Could not load type" after refactoring class name

Tags: asp.net, iis

I was trying to change the name of an aspx file from "Cennik.aspx" to "Serwis.aspx". I've changed three files: .aspx, .aspx.cs and .aspx.designer.cs. What is more I've also changed class name from CennikPage to SerwisPage and updated every occurence in those files.

Aspx file header is updated too:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/OneColumn.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
Inherits="NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Web.SerwisPage" Codebehind="Serwis.aspx.cs" %>
```

I've searched if there were any other occurrences of CennikPage, but with no results.

I get the following error:

> Could not load type
>   'NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Web.SerwisPage'.
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String
>   text, VirtualPath virtualPath,
>   Encoding fileEncoding) at

I restarted the website, changed AppPool from 4.0 Integrated to 4.0 classic and back and have tried many other things (also from similar topics here on SO) no result..

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you deploy the rebuild DLLs? Since you changed class names, you would need to.

Comment: I've changed those files directly on the server via ftp and did not deploy anything. I thought that it should get recompiled automatically.. ASP.NET AFAIK has two types of applications: "web site" which is a collection of aspx filesa(and others) and "web application" that is a dll. What am I missing?

Comment: Deploying helped. Still I don't understand why. This should compile automatically as it always did..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `Inherits` attribute value matches the new class name (and namespace).

If you changed the file name, update the `Codebehind` attribute value as well.

Comment: It does match. I've re-checked that dozens of times probably, because I'm freaking out.

Comment: @kubal5003 - Try clearing out the temporary internet files from the system folders.

Comment: I can't do it because it's on a shared hosting. I guess I'll try to build the whole solution under VS and deploy it to the server. Hope this helps.

Comment: @kubal5003 - That might be your problem... the site might not be compiling. Did you redeploy the binaries in the bin folder as well?